# Kubuntu 22.10 broke aplay's ability to play at the same time as WWOZ radio streaming

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

When I run `aplay chimp.wav`, I get the sound of a chimpanzee screaming (which totally annoys the missus).

However, when my FireFox is also playing https://www.wwoz.org/listen/player/ , so I can listen to the awesome music of New Orleans, `aplay` says this:

```
$ aplay script/chimp.wav
aplay: main:831: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Previous [K]Ubuntus worked correctly, but a fresh install of 22.10 (on a Lenovo ThinkPad L14) has this bug.

Searching for this bug returns various ways to screw with the ALSA drivers, which I don't think I should need to do...

(The point of the chimp screaming is so I can hear across the house if my half-hour test batch has failed)

---

The workaround is to use `cvlc --play-and-exit`.

Even `mplayer` sometimes worked and most of the time did not.

The question remains open because this is a regression in `aplay` and `mplayer` compared to previous versions.

---

the accepted fix worked for a while, then `cvlc` stopped working.

I ran `do-release-upgrade` and got me some 23.04, and now `cvlc` stopped working but `aplay` started working. Even if Firefox is playing internet radio.

elmoShrug.gif

Comment: just a note - `$ aplay ... & aplay ...` has the bug too

Comment: `mplayer` worked for a while then went mute. I suppose I could start reading the logs...

Comment: and `cvlc` literally got too quiet to hear over the radio. FML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.10 moved from Pulseaudio to Pipewire as the sound server solution. This might explain the issue.

I don't have 22.10 handy, but check out https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e?permalink_comment_id=4284672
especially this part:

ALSA
Single step. Copy the config file from the PipeWire examples into your ALSA configuration directory:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/doc/pipewire/examples/alsa.conf.d/99-pipewire-default.conf /etc/alsa/conf.d/
```

Comment: thanks! I got as far as `systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service` and then `cvlc` started working again. I didn't need to move the `alsa.conf` files. But `aplay` doesn't work. You would have won the bounty anyway but I was a day late granting it because the client had me on a special project sry